# Error in compilation on theos IOS "Id returned 1 exit status"

Tags: ios, cydia, tweak, theos

I would like to compile a Tweak with Theos on my iDevice (iTouch 4G IOS 6.1.3) but I have this error.!

Link of image : http://hpics.li/d090438

Help me please !

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, It looks like it has a problem with your -arch line

You need to use armv7 or armv7s or arm64 for new 64bit processor.